# Need a functional interface to manipulate a String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have to stream through a set of key/value pairs and modify each key (not value) to remove a prepended string. I'm trying to do it in one statement, but need a little help with it.

I'm sure I need a `.map()` operation, but I can't quite get it going. Here's my code before trying any conversion:

```
Map<String, String> properties = configs.stream()
                .flatMap(config -> config.getProperties().entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (left, right) -> right));
```

So my naive solution was to wrap `Map.Entry::getKey` in a `String` function, but I get a compile error saying that a functional interface is required. Is there something out-of-the-box I can use here, or do I really need to implement my own interface to get rid of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    ...
```

you can use

```
Collectors.toMap(
    e -> StringUtils.removeStart(e.getKey(), "prefix to remove"),
    ...
```

or

```
Collectors.toMap(
    e -> e.getKey().substring("prefix to remove".length()),
    ...
```

in case you don't have Apache Commons dependency